# Angular Print Checked boxes to an area

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a list of checkboxes... when any of them are checked I want them to print in the area where I use the {{}}... If it is not checked then I want there to be no visual sign that there is anything there... see my sandbox here http://plnkr.co/edit/lvkdCmg7dQabuRKsBT5A?p=preview

```
                            <!doctype html>
            <html ng-app>
            <head>
              <meta charset="utf-8">
              <title>AngularJS Multiple Checkboxes</title>
              <style>
                label {display: block;}
              </style>
              <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.js"></script>
            </head>

            <body>
              <div class="col-sm-7">
                  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="fali">
                  fa-li
                  <br>
                  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="falg">
                  fa-lg
                  <br>
                  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="fa2x">
                  fa-2x
                  <br>
                  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="fa3x">
                  fa-3x
                  <br>
                  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="fa4x">
                  fa-4x
                  <br>
                  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="fa5x">
                  fa-5x
                  <br>
                  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="spin">
                  fa-spin
                </div>
                <div class="col sm-4">
                  <xmp class="prettyprint">
                   <i class="fa {{fali}} {{falg}} {{fa2x}} {{fa3x}} {{fa4x}} {{fa5x}} {{spin}}"></i>
                  </xmp>
                </div>

              <script>

              </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

It works currently but it shows true/false instead of the value and it has a space in the string for non checked items

Comment: You have no code written in your Plunkr..

Comment: Does this work http://plnkr.co/edit/lvkdCmg7dQabuRKsBT5A?p=preview

Comment: Have you written any of the JS yet? The script.js on the plunkr has no code.

Comment: I loaded angular... I dont know what script I need.. It works currently but it shows true/false instead of the value and it has a space in the string for non checked items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` to specify the value you want. Otherwise the value is `true` or `false`.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="fa-li" ng-false-value="" ng-model="fali">
      fa-li
```

Updated plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/8BxnlsrvIhPmrGup7UaV?p=preview

Comment: Aactually I did not have to set them to false I had spaces between {{}}. There should not have been spaces... Thank you!

Comment: Ok... i jumped the gun... I need spaces between each only when the checked is true... I tried simply adding 'ng-true-value="fa-li "'but angular did not read the space.. I cannot add it between {{}} or it will always be there

Comment: I thought maybe adding &nbsp; in there would work, but nope. Is there a reason you cannot have hard-coded spaces in there? Yes, it's not pretty, but does it work? I added spaces into a font-awesome icon in a project and it just took out any extra spaces when the browser parsed it. I did it in run-time via the chrome dev tools and it still worked, even with the extra spaces between classes. The icon still looked correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-true-value="your value"` and `ng-false-value="your value"` on your checkbox elements to give values aside from `true` and `false` to checkboxes. To show the text initially, set your models to `false`.

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/V4IA9uUS4feDXcXC4BMk?p=preview

Comment: I need spaces between each one but ng-true-value="" will not cary spaces to the string... I cannot add spaces between the {{}} because the initial string will have too many. HELP